# Read text file as numpy array using np.loadtxt

Tags: arrays, numpy, text, python-2.6

I am trying to read a text file as a numpy array. For some reason one of the files is read fine, but an error (X = np.array(X, dtype) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.) is reported for another.

The code is:

```
   freq_chan = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(dirs,fil), skiprows = 6+int(no_nodes))
```

The row of the file that is read is:

```
 45.000000000000        1.73145123922036E-002  -2.27352994577858E-004    0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000
```

and the row of the file that is not read is:

```
450.00000000000        1.75123936984107E-003   4.99078580749004E-004  -1.01870220257046E-005  -1.25748632064143E-005   4.53694668200015E-004   1.75279359420616E-003   1.06388230080026E-005   1.25165432922695E-005  -1.26393875391086E-003
```

What might be the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: Why does the second row contain 3 more elements than the first one?

Comment: It's just different files. But why should that effect np.loadtxt?

Comment: Because of "I am trying to read a text file", I read "(the row of the file) that is not read" instead of "the row of (the file that is not read)", thinking there was only one file.

Comment: Is still a problem?  There have been various SO about `loadtxt` and this ValueError, but they aren't reproduceable.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is a problem with your delimiter character at least in the first file.  try to set the `delimiter` argument.

Take a look to [this explanation](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/frequent_errors.html#error-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)